# Sql query with more WHERE parameters in ASP.NET, is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sqldatasource

So here's my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="UsersSearchResult" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = :userparameter1 OR FIRSTNAME = :userparameter2 OR LASTNAME = :userparameter3 OR
        USERNAME = :userparameter4 OR PASSWORD = :userparameter5 OR EMAIL = :userparameter6 OR GENDER = :userparameter7 OR
        BIRTHDATE = :userparameter8 OR NATIONALITY = :userparameter9 OR CURRENTCITY = :userparameter10">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchUsersBox" Name="userparameter1" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchUsersBox" Name="userparameter2" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchUsersBox" Name="userparameter3" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchUsersBox" Name="userparameter4" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchUsersBox" Name="userparameter5" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchUsersBox" Name="userparameter6" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchUsersBox" Name="userparameter7" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchUsersBox" Name="userparameter8" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchUsersBox" Name="userparameter9" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchUsersBox" Name="userparameter10" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What I'm trying to do here is that when one search parameter looks into each column in the database using OR statements. Can I do that? If yes, how?

Comment: Are you sure you only care if 1 parameter matches? If someone ask for all FirstName = John in Nationality = USA, if you OR it, then all records that have a FirstName of John OR that has a Nationality of USA will be returned. When you have multiple user inputs, normally you AND the terms to make your filter search condition more narrow.

Comment: So that should work. What makes you think it didn't or won't?

Comment: @Conrad Frix It doesn't work, because it shows an ORA-01722 invalid number exception and I have no idea how to deal with that.

Comment: @kisbovan93: In that case the `WHERE` clause is a red herring. Isolate which parameter is causing trouble by splitting the clause in half, checking which half still raises the exception, then repeating the split-and-check until there's only one parameter left. If you need to, rewrite this question accordingly, but right now it's not actually about `WHERE`.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy, Yep, it had a problem with the ID query. This means that I can't make a query on Ints? Because the rest are all strings. Or how can I get it to work with decimals/ints?

Comment: @kisbovan93 use [TO_CHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm) e..g `TO_CHAR(TheIntField) = :userparameter1 `

Answer (score -1):

you have to use `where name1,name2,name3 OR name1,name2,name3`

Comment: This doesn't look like correct SQL syntax, and anyway it's not particularly clear exactly how you expect the OP to change their code to match this.